# モバイル回線経由でのRaspberry Piを遠隔操作するための構成

Tags: raspberry-pi

モバイル回線経由でのRaspberry Piを遠隔操作するための構成で悩んでいます。
AndroidまたはiOSからモバイル回線経由でラズパイを遠隔操作したいのですが、携帯基地局等を跨いだ時にIPも変わるのでうまく接続できるものがないか探していますが、いまいちいいものが見つかりません。
下記のような構成で考えています。
iOS・Android---携帯回線---基地局---インターネット---基地局---携帯回線---ラズパイ

やはり下記の構成でプロトコルはwebsocket等を使うのが無難でしょうか。
iOS・Android---携帯回線---基地局---インターネット---中継サーバ---基地局---携帯回線---ラズパイ

Comment: 操作対象のRasPiも携帯回線経由のようなので、ここでIPアドレスが固定に決まらず困る、という事でしょうか。具体的にどんな事をしようとしているのかもあわせて質問文に含めてもらうと回答もつきやすいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

仰られるように websocket を使う方法の他に reverse ssh tunnel もよく使われています

後者では [remot3.it](https://www.remot3.it/web/index.html) というサービス（昔は weaved という名前でした）が RPi の出始めの頃からあり、よく使っていました

remot3のサーバを中継して、モバイル回線の先の RPi に対してインターネットに接続されている別の端末から ssh で接続したり、httpd でコマンドを送ったりできます

Answer (score 1):

国内なら、SMS(ショートメッセージ）を使うのはどうでしょうか。

システムの構成は、以下のような感じです。

スマートフォン（コントローラ側）＝＝　携帯電話回線　＝＝　[Soracom Air] - Raspberry Pi

スマートフォンとSoracom Airは、それぞれが決まった電話番号を持っていて、相手の電話番号にSMSを送受することで、動作を指示したり、状態を確認したりできるかと思います。
インターネットは使わないので、IPがどうのこうのとか、電話回線とインターネットの間の接続とかいった面倒を避けられて良いと思います。

参考（この記事が発想の起点になっています）：[Raspberry PiとSoracom AirでSMSの送受信](https://mag.switch-science.com/2016/08/22/raspberry-pi-soracom-air-sms/)

Answer (score -1):

ダイナミックDNSというのもありますね。
下記のサイトを参照してみてください。
http://denshikousaku.net/raspberry-pi-domain-and-dynamic-dns